# Unable to locate appropriate constructor Expected arguments are: java.lang.String

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, dto

I have been completely unable to get Hibernate with DTOs. Not even very simple object with a single string, it *always* complains about "Unable to locate appropriate constructor" :(

I started with real code but tried to narrow it down and it doesn't even work with a class with a single String member (The Database is Sybase, the queries with Entities work, but DTOs do not):

I have this DTO class:

```
package com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class DummyDTO {
    private java.lang.String loginId;

    DummyDTO(java.lang.String loginId)
    {
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }
}
```

and this Named Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="getDummy", query="select new com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO ('String')"),
```

I also tried to query a table (instead of a literal) with this query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="getDummy", query="select new com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO (u.loginId) from User u"),
```

and this code to call it:

```
public Optional<DummyDTO> getDummy() {
    logger.info("getDummy()");
    TypedQuery<DummyDTO> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getDummy", DummyDTO.class);
    Optional<DummyDTO> optDummy = query.getResultList().stream().findFirst();
    if (optDummy.isPresent()) {
        logger.info(optDummy.get().toString());
    }
    return optDummy;
}
```

and it *always* crashes and produces several pages of stack traces:

```
21:02:01,302 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker] (default task-1)  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]
21:02:01,303 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker] (default task-1)  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]:  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models.DummyDTO]
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1245)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2375)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2241)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1507)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:589)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:317)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:265)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:157)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:588)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:331)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.ElsUserStorageProviderFactory.create(ElsUserStorageProviderFactory.java:154)
        at deployment.els-user-store-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.ElsUserStorageProviderFactory.create(ElsUserStorageProviderFactory.java:39)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.storage.AbstractStorageManager.getStorageProviderInstance(AbstractStorageManager.java:229)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.storage.AbstractStorageManager.lambda$getEnabledStorageProviders$0(AbstractStorageManager.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:400)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:210)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:723)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:71)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:15)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.10.5//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:328)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-crypto@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$2(ServerResponseWriter.java:151)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:399)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:219)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:95)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:530)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:461)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.4//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.4//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.2.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: I suggest you try making the constructor public.

Comment: As @danglingelse suggested, try making the constructor public. If it still does not work, create a no-arg constructor public DummyDto() {} then add setter and getter to the loginId field.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your DTO's as follows:

```
package com.epsilon.keycloakuserstore.models;
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DummyDTO {
    private String loginId;

}
```